# 'preprint' option causes long table extend across a page in REVTex

Tags: tables, longtable, revtex

I usually use the `preprint` class to save a pdf draft for showing to others. However, there is a small issue. `preprint` adds line space between table rows as well and the long tables may now extend the page, making it very ugly.

Tex file with `preprint` option. (Compare with `reprint` which looks perfect.)

```
\documentclass[jcp,preprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\draft 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling elegance do shutters appetite yourself diverted. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. Is allowance instantly strangers apet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte.  Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
Suscipit donec potenti per aenean Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci
Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula 


\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table*}[h]
    \caption{some random table caption A2}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}   

            \textbf{test} &  \textbf{test}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc6,dd}$} &  \textbf{test} &  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & \textbf{test} &             {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{95}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{17}$} & \textbf{test} \\
            \cmidrule{1-12}
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9325 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.95125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9725 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.042 & 6.64438 & 0.109125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.4125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 2.9125 & 0.9241 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9325 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.95125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9725 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.042 & 6.64438 & 0.109125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
            275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.4125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}
\endgroup






\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table*}[h]
    \caption{\label{table:Anisotropy_ME_tableD2} just a caption here.}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}

275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    

            \cmidrule{1-11} 
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    

        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}
\endgroup


\section{Results}
Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laug
se no he summer lovers twenty in. Not his difficulty boisterous surrounded bed. Seems folly if in given scale nted dependent conveying advantage can use. 
\section{Discussion}
Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling el excellence how her pianoforte. 
\section{appendix}
Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down th eagerness assurance additions to. 
\end{document}
```

How to deal with such case. I can use additional package to shorten the table as much as possible. 
(I have tried changing the text size `small`, `footnotesize` which did not help.)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}` maybe? Or if you don't mind the `preprint` option giving singlespacing for the whole document, then passing `tightenlines` to the document class options will work as well.

Comment: @Troy :   Thanks for the ideas. Could you elaborate how to change the spacing in preprint.

Comment: Which spacing are you referring to? First try placing `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}` in the preamble (i.e. before `\begin{document}`) and see if you're satisfied with the results.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}` does the job. The table rows are compact now, while the text line spacing is not affected. Thanks.

Comment: @Troy  : Could you please answer this question using the comment. This would help to close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}` to make your table more compact in the vertical direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[jcp,preprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75} % <-----------
\draft 

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling elegance do shutters appetite yourself diverted. Distrusts allowance do knowledge eagerness assurance additions to. Is allowance instantly strangers apet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte.  Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula tellus non nullam quisque class sem donec volutpat donec netus arcu
    Suscipit donec potenti per aenean Ultrices aenean interdum blandit neque lectus orci
    Adipiscing lacinia fermentum cubilia nisl vehicula 


    \begingroup
    \squeezetable
    \begin{table*}[h]
        \caption{some random table caption A2}
        \begin{ruledtabular}
            \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}   

                \textbf{test} &  \textbf{test}  & {$\langle\bar{\alpha\beta}\rangle_{cc6,dd}$} &  \textbf{test} &  {$\langle \bar{\alpha\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\zeta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & {$\langle \bar{\beta\epsilon}\rangle_{aa,bb}$} & \textbf{test} &             {$\langle {\gamma}\rangle_{95}$}& {$\langle {\epsilon}\rangle_{17}$} & \textbf{test} \\
                \cmidrule{1-12}
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9325 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.95125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9725 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.042 & 6.64438 & 0.109125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.4125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 2.9125 & 0.9241 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9325 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.95125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.9725 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.042 & 6.64438 & 0.109125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 0.4125 & 0.9141 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\

            \end{tabular}
        \end{ruledtabular}
    \end{table*}
    \endgroup






    \begingroup
    \squeezetable
    \begin{table*}[h]
        \caption{\label{table:Anisotropy_ME_tableD2} just a caption here.}
        \begin{ruledtabular}
            \begin{tabular}{rccccccccccc}

                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    

                \cmidrule{1-11} 
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    
                275.36 & 6.0322 & 6.6438 & 099125 & 0.9341 & 0.9174 & 0.9223 & 0.9289 & 0.9370 & 0.5567 & 0.9579 & 0.9707 \\                    

            \end{tabular}
        \end{ruledtabular}
    \end{table*}
    \endgroup


    \section{Results}
    Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laug
    se no he summer lovers twenty in. Not his difficulty boisterous surrounded bed. Seems folly if in given scale nted dependent conveying advantage can use. 
    \section{Discussion}
    Man request adapted spirits set pressed. Up to denoting subjects sensible feelings it indulged directly. We dwelling el excellence how her pianoforte. 
    \section{appendix}
    Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down th eagerness assurance additions to. 
\end{document}
```